# jQuery UI Slide Content Out, New Content In

Tags: jquery, user-interface, slide

I am trying to achieve this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8m1D.gif

Using [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) | [Slide](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide)

I sadly have no code to present to be fixed, I am looking for any direction you can give me on how to achieve this. It needs to travel left a set distance, then return back to it's initial starting spot and reveal the content relevant to which anchor they clicked. Apologies for having no code to begin with, I am fairly new to JavaScript.

Really appreciate any help or advice you can offer,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `.animate()` function is easier, since it provides a callback function for the animation

```
$(function () {
    var wid = $('.content').width(); 
    $('.content').animate({"margin-right": "-" + wid + "px"}, 500, function ()   {

        $(this).text("new content");
        $('.content').animate({"margin-right": "0px"}, 500);
    });
});
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/JMqpe/1/

This code, will move the box, all the way to the right (same amount as it's width), update the content, now that it's hidden, then return to its original position (assuming that it's margin-right was 0 to begin with)